# Problemas de fecha con java

Tags: java

Mi pregunta es la siguiente, Trabajo en una Base de datos, intentando cargar un archivo excel de donde debemos extraer las fechas de la columna correspondiente del archivo,el codigo java me manda error, cabe aclarar que la base de datos acepta el formato dd/MMM/yyyy y el archivo excel tiene un formato dd/yyyy, por lo cual he intentado extraer el año del nombre del archivo y anexarlo a un nuevo formato de fecha. Adjunto mi código ya que ya me he frustrado de conseguirle si alguien tiene alguna idea para esto se lo agradeceria.

```
=try {
     import java.util.Date;
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;


String yearMonth = vcAdditional30.split("_")[2];
yearMonth = yearMonth.replace(".xls", "");
String date2="";

date2 =validateData+"-"+yearMonth

String completeDate="";
SimpleDateFormat addYear = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
SimpleDateFormat getDayMonth = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");

completeDate = getDayMonth.format(date2);

validateData = addYear.parse(completeDate);
System.out.println(validateData);



} catch (Exception e) {
 codeError = e.toString();
resultValidate = false;
}
```

Comment: te recomiendo revisar tu codiya que como lo tienes actulmente no compila, y por lo tanto no es un [mcve]

Comment: Alguna idea de como podria realizar este metodo dentro de la base de datos, ya que no encuentro una solución efectiva

Comment: Pon en el título _cuál es el problema_, y como te han dicho, adjunta un [repro]. Además, pulsa en [edit] y menciona _cuál es el error_ al que haces referencia.